# No warning at undefined variables in PyCharm Community 2017.2

Tags: python, pycharm, code-inspection

I have this piece of code in a Python module open in PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.

```
class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = 5
        self.prop2 = 10

    def method1(self):
        return foo

    def do_work(self):
        not_defined_func()


s = Sample()
s.method1()

bar = call_func
```

The IDE doesn't give any warnings on some fairly serious issues:

1. The returned variable `foo` has not been defined.
2. I assign not defined variable `call_func` to the variable `bar`.
3. I call not defined function `not_defined_func` inside the method `do_work`.

How do I enable PyCharm to highlight these things? I have a fresh installation of PyCharm and have all the `Inspections` enabled in `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python`.

Comment: Did you solve this? I just had a similar problem [not getting warnings about unresolved references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66721578).

Answer (score 2):

See which python interpreter is enabled go to preference > Project > Project Interpreter. Set python interpreter and then apply it. 
Also check if inspections are enabled.

Comment: Both of those things are set, but I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Editor > Inspections and select Python, click settings icon and "Restore Defaults" then apply.

Comment: This removes any custom changes you've made. It also doesn't help if this setting was already turned on.