# Why doesn't PyCharm show variable spelling errors?

Tags: pycharm

For examples:

```
transformed = self._transform(pattern_object)
self.patterns[channel].append(transformered)
```

'transformered' is a wrong spelling of 'transformed'. But my PyCharm doesn't highlight it in red flag and only reports it when I run the program. It used to display the error immediately. Is there some setting to control this? I didn't change anything, or I accidentally changed some settings I am not aware of.

Comment: You can check if error highlighting is at level "Highlight: All Problems" by clicking at the problem indicator on the top right of your editor. If so, you can also check if the "Proofreading > Typo" and "Python > Unresolved references" inspection is enabled in "Preferences > Editor > Inspections".

Comment: Strange that both are already checked in by default. and that is why I said i didn't change anything. But it still didn't display the error.

Comment: Strong possibility you have [Reader Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721578) activated. Try checking the [Error and warning highlighting, inspection widget](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reader-mode.html) or disabling it completely.

Comment: @bad_coder You are absolutely right!